# Insert data into temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I'm trying to build a temporary Table where it have a column retrieved by an currently exciting table and insert in each row a date.

For example I have

```
select NumberID into #Table0
from Table1
where numcue in [conditions]
```

In the new Table0 I have the NumberID ordered by a certain criteria. But in that exact same order I want to introduce a date for each row.

Is there any way to do it without using a CREATE TABLE, or INSERT ( I don't have permissions for that)

Thanks in advance

***-------EDITION--- (MORE INFO)***

Maybe I wasn't clear about it, long story short is that I have IDNUMBER in the TABLE1 on my Datawarehouse (10k+rows), but it have 20 dates for each IDNUMBER.

In an Excel I have the date I need to retrieve for each IDNUMBER, but I don't know how to retrieve that exact info directly with a QUERY. And the dates doesn't have a criteria is just random date for each IDNUMBER so I can't code it directly.

So what I was trying to do, is put each IDNUMBER with the date of the Excel in a temporary Table and then keep looking info with that

Hope this help to explain a little further

Thanks in advance and for all the current answers

Comment: You can create a View from the ids of the Table0 (if you can use CREATE VIEW priviledge) and for each tuple in the view, pass the desire date?

Comment: A date?  What date?

Comment: A `#Table0` is **not** a *temporal* table - it's s **temporary** table ....

Answer (score 0):

So you mean something like this?

```
select NumberID, GETDATE() AS DateColumn into #Table0
from Table1
where numcue in [conditions]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using a CTE (Common Table Expression) to find the row number for your ID's.
I'm not sure if this is the case, but I've understood you want to increment the date for each row, e.g.:

```
 NumberID|Date
      1  |2018-01-01
      3  |2018-01-02
     12  |2018-01-03
     25  |2018-01-04
```

In that case, I've supplied some code that uses the sys_objects table as an example:

```
    DECLARE @FirstDate DATE = '20180101'
    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT object_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id ASC) AS RowNumber
            FROM master.sys.objects
            ORDER BY object_id
    )
    SELECT  object_id, DATEADD(dd, RowNumber-1, @FirstDate) AS Date, RowNumber
        FROM CTE;
```

[image: Example]
You can ignore the RowNumber column - I've just added for you to understand that it is a sequence.

For you case in particular, I think this code should work - remember to specify your initial date:

```
    DECLARE @FirstDate DATE = '20180101'
    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT NumberID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NumberID ASC) AS RowNumber 
            FROM Table1
            WHERE numcue IN [conditions]
    )
    SELECT NumberID, DATEADD(dd, RowNumber-1, @FirstDate) AS Date
        FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thank you, its pretty usefull to be honest. But in this case what I want to do is introduce data, maybe I shouldn't have said that is a date type data. But the real problem here is that I have something like this in an Excel.

IDNumber        Date
1                      2017-01-01
2                      2018-02-01
...

I can retrieve the IDNumber from a currently exciting table, but the date is something I only have in Excel.